# Two active apache instances with different php versions

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

Currently i have one apache(2.0) server with php (5.2.0). My goal is to start different apache server with other php version(5.6.17) on different port without stopping the old one because my colleague is working on it. Im not so sure is that the best way to do that, i accept new suggestions.

PS - I can stop old apache for a short time if it's necessary.

Can i use the one apache instance for the different php versions and sepparate them with virtualhost files or something like that?

Server OS - Windows Server 2008 R2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Also you could start installed apache with different config.

Comment: You mean, second Apache with it's own config file or  one(old) Apache with two separate configs files?